# After manually fail over resume button is disabled and query doesn't resumes

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

> As there is no witess available, so when resumes the mirrored database by

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET PARTNER RESUME;
```

> does not resumes the mirroring. Resume button is also disabled. I don't get any error. What is the checkpoint?

Comment: what is principal and mirror database status?

Comment: hope it will help you out https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/080d9a9c-a634-4742-8ac5-9e32befc1b11/mirroring-has-been-stopped-since-long-time-i-am-resuming-but-still-it-is-showing-as-suspended?forum=sqldatabasemirroring.

Comment: I have found the error, Master Server and Mirror has different SQL Server Version.

Comment: I think you upgraded mirror server. right? if yes then SQL Server does not support mirroring across different version & edition. You'll have to upgrade principal server to keep it working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also check on the SQL errors? What does it says...?

One thing you can try is to restart your endpoint mirroring on both the primary and secondary instance to see if it helps.

(Stop the endpoint mirroring first)

ALTER ENDPOINT  STATE=STOPPED

(Then start it back up)

ALTER ENDPOINT  STATE=STARTED